# How to use an Autoencoder for anomaly detection?

Tags: neural-networks, anomaly-detection

I would like to use an [Autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder) for anomaly detection and I wonder how to detect them basically. This is a general question but also related to an implementation as I use time series data. That's why I think I have to use a rolling window but when I want to detect trends I think I will extend my model with a LSTM with which a rolling window makes no sense(?).
Nevertheless, to detect anomalies it is common to use the reconstruction error - but how do I do that? I cut the model into halves (encoder and decoder) and use only the decoder for the reconstruction.
But I have to train the model all the time, right?

Atm my training data contains data of three months in hourly steps. And test data is one month.

Answer (score 1):

Both the encoder and decoder is used when computing the reconstruction error. So to compute anomaly score you just pass new samples through the trained autoencoder.

If you have enough data you might periodically retrain the model to compensate for trends. For example use the last N weeks as the window for training data, and retrain once per week.

Detecting trends should probably be considered as a separate problem to your anomaly detector. Classic methods like ARIMA etc might be useful there.